# Symfony 4 login Guard authenticator errors

Tags: authentication, symfony4

On login page I get this in dev.log:

```
**Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"} []**
```

Plus on the register page, after submitting I get

```
**The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.**
```

And in dev.log:

```
**Guard authentication failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\InvalidCsrfTokenException(code: 0):**
```

The same code is working on my colleague's machine cannot get where can be the problem.

security.yaml

```yaml
        firewalls:
        static_pages:
            pattern:    ^/static
            security:   false
            
        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/token
            security:   false

        oauth_authorize:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/auth
            security:   false
            # Add your favorite authentication process here

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            user_checker: security.user_checker
            form_login:
                provider: app_user
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: app_homepage
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            guard:
                provider: app_user
                entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\GoogleAuthenticator
                    - App\Security\FacebookAuthenticator
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
```

SecurityController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Identity;

use App\Controller\BaseController;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Security\AuthenticationManager;
use App\Util\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\NativePasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

/**
 * Class SecurityController
 */
class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     *
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin-login", name="app_security_admin_login", methods={"POST", "GET"})
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function adminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $session Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $authErrorKey = Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
        $lastUsernameKey = Security::LAST_USERNAME;

        // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
        if ($request->attributes->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get($authErrorKey);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $session->get($authErrorKey);
            $session->remove($authErrorKey);
        } elseif ($request->query->has('error')) {
            $error = $request->query->get('error');
        } else {
            $error = null;
        }

        if (!$error instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            $error = null; // The value does not come from the security component.
        }

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = (is_null($session)) ? '' : $session->get($lastUsernameKey);

        $tokenManager = $this->getToken();

        $csrfToken = $tokenManager
            ? $tokenManager->getToken('authenticate')->getValue()
            : null;

        return $this->render('Security/admin_login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/admin-login-check", name="app_security_admin_login_check", methods={"POST", "GET"})
     *
     * @param Request     $request
     * @param UserManager $userManager
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function adminLoginCheck(Request $request, UserManager $userManager)
    {
        $username = $request->request->get('_username');
        $password = $request->request->get('_password');

        $encoders = new NativePasswordEncoder(13);
        $factory = new EncoderFactory([$encoders]);

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

        if(!$user){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_security_admin_login',
                ['error' => 'Username doesnt exists']
            );
        }

        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder(User::class);
        $salt = $user->getSalt();

        if(!$encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $salt)) {
            return $this->render("Security/admin_login.html.twig", [
                'error' => 'Username or Password not valid'
            ]);
        }

        $token = $this->get(AuthenticationManager::class)->authenticate($user);

        return $this->redirectToRoute("admin_homepage");
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_security_login", methods={"POST", "GET"})
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $session Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $authErrorKey = Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
        $lastUsernameKey = Security::LAST_USERNAME;

        /** get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below) */
        if ($request->attributes->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get($authErrorKey);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $session->get($authErrorKey);
            $session->remove($authErrorKey);
        } else {
            $error = null;
        }

        if (!$error instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            $error = null; // The value does not come from the security component.
        }

        /** last username entered by the user */
        $lastUsername = (is_null($session)) ? '' : $session->get($lastUsernameKey);

        $tokenManager = $this->getToken();

        $csrfToken = $tokenManager
            ? $tokenManager->getToken('authenticate')->getValue()
            : null;

        return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig',[
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="app_security_check", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function checkAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration.');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_security_logout", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException('You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.');
    }

    protected function getToken()
    {
        return $this->get("security.csrf.token_manager");
    }
}
```

I could provide other files if needed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the path for the session even though the log complained about other things:

```yaml
# config/packages/framework.yaml
session:
  save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
```