# Symfony 4.4 Security / Session is saved but not used

Tags: security, authentication, session, symfony4

*Full config files are available bellow.*

My website is using **2 guards** at differents entries :

- `lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator` to access the `^/api` routes
- `App\Security\LoginAuthenticator` to access `^/secured` routes

The JWT authetification is working well, allowing users to call a API plateform routes such as `localhost/api/types`

The problem is about using the `LoginAuthenticator` session. This is the basic symfony configuration (auto-generated files with `php bin/console make:auth`)

When login with correct user/password, the guard save a session to `app/var/sessions/dev/sess_ras4up86e1c8a1bs9khr5t7scg`

When the session is saved and set, the `LoginAuthenticator` trigger `onAuthenticationSuccess` function redirecting the user to route name `test.

But the `testController` is not working, redirecting the user to login page (`302 HTTP code`). It also throwing the following error in `var/log/dev/dev.log` :

```
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login"},"request_uri":"https://krang.local/login","method":"POST"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"login","authenticators":1} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"login","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Calling getCredentials() on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"login","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Passing guard token information to the GuardAuthenticationProvider {"firewall_key":"login","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.is_active AS is_active_4, t0.roles AS roles_5, t0.customer_id AS customer_id_6 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["matthieu"] []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.INFO: Guard authentication successful! {"token":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Guard\\Token\\PostAuthenticationGuardToken: PostAuthenticationGuardToken(user=\"matthieu\", authenticated=true, roles=\"ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN\"))","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator set success response. {"response":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\RedirectResponse: HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nCache-Control: no-cache, private\r\nDate:          Thu, 08 Jul 2021 11:07:40 GMT\r\nLocation:      /secured/backmarketProducts\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n        <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url='/secured/backmarketProducts'\" />\n\n        <title>Redirecting to /secured/backmarketProducts</title>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        Redirecting to <a href=\"/secured/backmarketProducts\">/secured/backmarketProducts</a>.\n    </body>\n</html>)","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Remember me skipped: it is not configured for the firewall. {"authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: The "App\Security\LoginAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called {"authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] request.INFO: Matched route "test". {"route":"test","route_parameters":{"_route":"test","_controller":"App\\Controller\\BackMarketController::productsList"},"request_uri":"https://krang.local/secured/backmarketProducts","method":"GET"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"secured","authenticators":1} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"secured","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"secured","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at /home/matthieu/krang/webservice/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:69)"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] request.INFO: Matched route "app_login". {"route":"app_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login"},"request_uri":"https://krang.local/login","method":"GET"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"login","authenticators":1} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"login","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"login","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"ad25b7"},"request_uri":"https://krang.local/_wdt/ad25b7","method":"GET"} []
```

We can see this error :

```
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"secured","authenticator":"App\\Security\\LoginAuthenticator"} []
[2021-07-08 13:07:40] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at /home/matthieu/krang/webservice/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:69)"} []
```

> Guard authenticator does not support the request

What does this mean ? I give you some useful code to checkout :

**security.yaml :** (full file)

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER : "ROLE_USER"
        ROLE_ADMIN : "ROLE_ADMIN"
        ROLE_SUPERADMIN : "ROLE_SUPERADMIN"

    providers:
        entity_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

        docs:
            pattern:  ^/docs
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

        secured:
            pattern: ^/secured
            stateless: true
            provider: entity_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator

        api:
            pattern:  ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: entity_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY  }
        - { path: ^/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
        - { path: ^/secured, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY  }
```

**SecurityController:** (unchanged from default)

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            die();
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

**LoginAuthenticator:** (src/Security/LoginAuthenticator.php)

```
class LoginAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('Username could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {

        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }
       return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('test'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

**BackMarketController** (just a function)
*function called on authentification success*

```
    /**
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @Route("/secured/backmarketProducts", name="test")
     */
    public function productsList(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('back_market/backmarketProducts.html.twig');
    }
```

About the webserver :

- Apache2
- Debian 8
- using HTTPS
- Symfony 4.4

I can give you more informations of course, just ask for it.

**What i tried by looking on other similar subjects :**

- [Symfony 4 login Guard authenticator errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396361/symfony-4-login-guard-authenticator-errors) (save the session information elsewhere from default)
- update project components
- [Symfony 4 login form : authenticating successfully, but authentication immediately lost after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902619/symfony-4-login-form-authenticating-successfully-but-authentication-immediate) (add `EquatableInterface` to `User` entity)
- Kill `onAuthenticationSuccess` **BEFORE REDIRECTION** **show on the profiler that a session is created but cant follow redirection** (look at the error above)

## **UPDATE 1 (3 days later)**

I found a way to allow jwt token and securityauthentificator to work together.

There is the security.yaml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER : "ROLE_USER"
        ROLE_ADMIN : "ROLE_ADMIN"
        ROLE_SUPERADMIN : "ROLE_SUPERADMIN"

    providers:
        entity_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                entry_point: lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\SecurityAuthenticator
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            json_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        docs:
            pattern:  ^/docs
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

        api:
            pattern:  ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: entity_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

        secured:
            pattern: ^/secured
            anonymous: false
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\SecurityAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY  }
        - { path: ^/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
        - { path: ^/secured, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY  }
```

I think that block solve the issue, the symfony security compenent got both guards declared on **main** firewall, using jwt by default.

To use the basic symfony auth system (`securityAuthentificator`) i just added a **secured** firewall providing SecurityAuthenticator

Is there a good way to work with security ? Does this trick seems legit ? Im not sure im providing a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody seems able to help me. In any case I solved the problem on my own.

There is my full functionnal **security.yaml** :

This config is working, making symfony able to use API PLATEFORM with JWT tokens and to log user on a simple back office application.

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER : "ROLE_USER"
        ROLE_ADMIN : "ROLE_ADMIN"
        ROLE_SUPERADMIN : "ROLE_SUPERADMIN"

    providers:
        entity_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                entry_point: lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\SecurityAuthenticator
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            json_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        docs:
            pattern:  ^/docs
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true

        api:
            pattern:  ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: false
            provider: entity_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

        secured:
            pattern: ^/secured
            anonymous: false
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\SecurityAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY  }
        - { path: ^/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
        - { path: ^/secured, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY  }
```